# WebKit based UI in a 3D application

Tags: c++, webkit

I want to use WebKit in C++ for a 3D game UI on Windows. So that 
the designer will be able to use HTML and JavaScript.
( I will either use http://sourceforge.net/projects/wke or code mine )

My question is :
I will need to call functions in C++ from UI , let`s say when a certain button in UI clicked,
that will trigger a code in C++.

Can this be achieved by implementing an intermediate Javascript file ?
If yes , how can it be done ?

If not , do I need to modify WebKit source code ? ( to catch web based events )

Answer (score 0):

[wke](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wke/) has its own bounding for C/C++, so you only need to learn it!

Comment: I checked its demos but I couldn`t see any interaction. ( Anyway I mailed to project owner ) Do you mean that WebKit also provides `bindings` ?